# In the 2019 WFRCC, did anyone catch up in a match after losing in the 'slow rapid' (classical?) portion?

Tags: fide, chess-variants, world-championship, chess960

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_World_Fischer_Random_Chess_Championship_2019)

> Each match of the quarterfinals consisted of two “slow” rapid games (45 minutes for 40 moves plus 15 minutes for the rest, without increment), two “fast” rapid games (15 minutes plus 2 seconds increment) and 2 blitz games (3 minutes plus 2 seconds increment). The games were weighted differently: 3 points for each slow rapid game, 2 points for each fast rapid game and 1 point for each blitz game.

I believe this applies to the semi-finals and finals too. For the 9 matches of the quarter-finals and the 4 matches of the semi-finals and finals (4 includes the 3rd place match), for anyone that lost the 45min ([slow rapid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6)? Classical?) portion of their match, did they catch up and win the overall match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but 5 out of 13 slow rapid portions were drawn. (However, none of the semi-finals or finals slow rapid portions were drawn.)

Semi-finals:

- Magnus vs Fabi - Magnus won the slow rapid 7.5-4.5 & then overall 12.5-7.5.
- Nepo vs Wesley So - Wesley So won the slow rapid 9-3 & then overall 13-5.

Finals & 3rd place:

- Nepo vs Fabi - Nepo won the slow rapid 7.5-4.5 & then overall 12.5-5.5.
- Magnus vs Wesley So - Wesley So won the slow rapid 10.5-1.5 & then overall 13.5-2.5.

Quarter-finals Day 1:

- [Svidler vs Fabi](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/psvidler?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&opponent=fabianocaruana&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - Fabi won the slow rapid 4.5-1.5 and then overall 7-5.
- [Wesley So vs Hikaru](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/gmwso?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - N/A - They drew the slow rapid.
- [Fedoseev vs Vidit](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/viditchess?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&opponent=bigfish1995&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - N/A - They drew the slow rapid.
- [Alireza vs Nepo (on Day 1)](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/lachesisq?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&opponent=firouzja2003&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - N/A - They drew the slow rapid.

Quarter-finals Day 2:

- [Vidit vs Alireza](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/viditchess?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&opponent=firouzja2003&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - N/A - They drew the slow rapid.
- [Wesley So vs Svidler](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/gmwso?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - N/A - They drew the slow rapid.

Quarter-finals Day 3:

- [Fedoseev vs Wesley So](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/gmwso?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - Wesley So won the slow rapid 4.5-1.5 and then overall 7-5.
- [Hikaru vs Fabi](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/hikaru?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&opponent=fabianocaruana&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - Fabi won the slow rapid 4.5-1.5 and then overall 6.5-1.5.
- [Alireza vs Nepo (again)](https://www.chess.com/games/archive/lachesisq?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&opponent=firouzja2003&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any) - Nepo won the slow rapid 4.5-1.5 and then overall 6.5-3.5.