# What were all the chess960 armageddon games played in St Louis Chess 9LX and the WFRCC, and which colour won in each?

Tags: chess-variants, world-championship, time-control, chess960, armageddon

Well I think I know for

- 2019 WFRCC 3rd qualifying round and onwards
- 2022 WFRCC qualifiers quarter-finals and onwards
- Every Chess 9LX

If anyone knows and has bothered to check the previous rounds, then please share! (I don't think there's armageddon in the other cases though since I think it's swiss not knockout.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [2019 WFRCC](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6)

1st & 2nd qualifying round:

- None I know of.

3rd qualifying round:

1. Robert Hess vs Tigran L Petrosian (as in the pipi pampers Wesley So "w"esley "s"o person) - [Robert won as Black](https://www.frchess.com/news/vidit-claims-spot-in-quarterfinals), but not via draw odds. [Game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/3969761067). 5min vs 4min.
2. Robert Hess vs Sergey Karjakin - [Sergey won as Black](https://www.frchess.com/news/vidit-claims-spot-in-quarterfinals), but not via draw odds. [Game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/3970082149).  5min vs 4min.
3. Oleg Badmatsyrenov vs Alexander 'Sasha' Grischuk - [Sasha won as Black](https://www.frchess.com/news/top-seeds-clash-again-in-qualifier-4) via draw odds. [Game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/3978410965).  5min vs 4min.

[Quarter-finals](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/in-the-2019-wfrcc-did-anyone-catch-up-in-a-match-after-losing-in-the-45min-port):

4. Ian 'Nepo' Nepomniachtchi vs Alireza Firouzja - [Nepo won as Black](https://www.frchess.com/news/quarterfinals-kick-off), but not via draw odds. [Game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/4090280149). 5min vs 4min.

Semi-finals and finals (including 3rd place) :

- None.

## [2022 WFRCC](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41483/why-didnt-wesley-so-get-full-championship-privilege-in-the-2022-wfrcc-unlike-ma) qualifiers quarter-finals and onwards

Swiss or round robin or whatever stages before the quarter-finals of any of the 4 qualifiers:

- None I know of.

Semi-finals of the 2nd chesscom qualifier:

1. Matthias Blübaum / Bluebaum vs Alexey Sarana - [Matthias won as Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_World_Fischer_Random_Chess_Championship_2022#Qualifier_2), via draw odds. [Game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/55610504763). 15min vs 11:10.

Quarter-finals and finals of the 1st chesscom qualifier:

2. Samuel Sevian - [Samuel won as White](https://www.chess.com/news/view/2022-fischer-random-world-championship-qualifier-1-d1). [Game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/55014370587). 15min vs 13min.

Quarter-finals and finals of the 2nd chesscom qualifier:

3. Daniel 'Danya' Naroditsky vs Pranav Venkatesh - [Danya won as Black](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiianDlRADk), but not via draw odds. [Game](https://www.chess.com/game/live/55604442313). 15min vs 11:25.

Quarter-finals, semi-finals and finals of the lichess qualifiers:

- None I know of.

Finals

4. Ian 'Nepo' Nepomniachtchi vs Hikaru Nakamura - Hikaru won as White. [Game](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fide-world-fischer-random-chess-championship/finals--armageddon/1jTLZRNH/UwCkIVUD). 15min vs 13min.

## Every Chess 9LX

1. Just Fabiano 'Fabi' Caruana vs Alireza Firouzja in 2022 - Fabi won as white. [Game](https://lichess.org/broadcast/2022-champions-showdown-chess-9lx/armageddon/5Y4OHCFK/lYR3Tj2h#0). 5min vs 4min.

---

## Statistics

**Note**: The 4 Armageddon games in the 2022 WFRCC are by bid with 15min vs something. The 5 Armageddon games in the 2019 WFRCC and in Chess 9LX are predetermined 5min vs 4min.

For all 9 games:  (White win rate is 1/3.)

Total games: 9

- White wins: 3
- Black wins normally: 4
- Black wins by draw odds: 2

For predetermined 5min vs 4min: (White win rate is 20%.)

Total games: 5

- White wins: 1
- Black wins normally: 3
- Black wins by draw odds: 1

For bid: (White win rate is 50%.)

Total games: 4

- White wins: 2
- Black wins normally: 1
- Black wins by draw odds: 1
- Black bids: 13,13,11:10,11:25. Average is 12min 8.75sec