# Is Armageddon always without increment?

Tags: statistics, time-control, mathematics, armageddon

[Robert Hess said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiianDlRADk) tells Danya that no increment influences why Robert prefers white to black in [Armageddon chess960](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41538/armageddon-does-should-white-have-a-lower-advantage-in-chess960-compared-to-c). Of course it really depends on the [bid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/8269#8269), but I guess Robert would want a lower bid for black compared to an analogous case where Armageddon would have increment.

Have there been Armageddon games (in chess, chess960, shogi, xiangqi, go/baduk, etc) with increment? So far I've seen [in chess960](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/what-were-all-the-chess960-armageddon-games-played-in-st-louis-chess-9lx-and-the) they're all without increment.

---

Comment: Please ask only one question per question otherwise your questions are likely to be closed.

Comment: @BrianTowers Thanks for the advice. In this case: I said if none. Because if there isn't, then there's not really much to discuss so i move on. If yes, then there's no reason to discuss why there isn't (since there is).

Comment: @BrianTowers [Why is it unfocused to ask another question in the event of an uneventful answer in a yes/no question?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/why-is-it-unfocused-to-ask-another-question-in-the-event-of-an-uneventful-answer) It's like if I ask on maths SE 'Do there exist objects with property X?'

If yes, then give example.

If no, then you'd expect a proof as to why such an object doesn't exist right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2013 USCC Alejandro Ramirez vs Gata Kamsky had increment.

[2013 U.S. Championships: Playoff (Part 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3Ova9ucsHk)

- 6:07 - 6:22 - It's a 5 second increment.
- 37:50 - 38:20 - Indeed both players get 5 second increment. Jen Shahade cites the increment as an explanation as to why players can afford to bid as low as, say, 18 min vs 45 min.