# Why did the later US chess championships or St Louis chess events remove auction & even increment from their armageddon?

Tags: tournament, uscf, armageddon, increment

It's stated by Jim Ratliff [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/32583#32583) that there was a 2013 United States Chess Championship (USCC) armageddon w/ auction that was 45 minutes base time + [5 second increment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41576/is-armageddon-always-without-increment). This [converts](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/time-control-conversion-when-it-comes-to-bonus-time-after-eg-40-moves) to only 50min, so it's still just rapid. However, apparently, there was a 60 minute armageddon w/ auction [game](https://chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1583077) in the 2010 USCC (also won by Gata Kamsky). This also had increment. From [thisweekinchess](https://theweekinchess.com/chessnews/events/us-championships-saint-louis-2010): (link added)

> Gata Kamsky defeated Yuri Shulman in a [rapid playoff](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44972/why-is-the-2010-uscc-between-gata-kamsky-yury-shulman-considered-rapid-not-cla) (Kamsky had black and 25 mins + 5 seconds a move (with draw odds) against Shulman's 1 hour + 5 seconds a move. This came from a bidding process)

However, later in for example the [2022 women's USCC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0HF3RB_j24) (Irina Krush vs Jennifer Yu) or the [2022 St Louis Chess9LX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmQDdnRXuBg) (Fabiano Caruana vs Alireza Firouzja) their armageddon doesn't have auction or increment.

**Question**: What did USCF or St Louis Chess Club say is the reason for this change?

Or alternatively, you can answer, if it's true, that there was some chess trend in the 2010s where they moved towards either

- such changes in armageddons or maybe
- faster armageddons, maybe aligned with how games in general became faster in the 2010s, though I don't see how this directly implies 'no increment' or 'no auction'. In the recent chess960 tournament 2024 Freestyle Chess, the armageddon game between Levon vs Fabi had an auction. But it didn't have increment. When [Fabi plays Nd6](https://youtu.be/41YEm9QAl9A?t=72), it looks like Fabi's time goes from 3:56 to 3:58. But then it goes back down to 3:55. Tania Sachdev says a few seconds later there's no increment.